# How to Select a Button with Multiple classes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

You want to select a html button with class `btn` in Jquery: `$('.btn')`. How about when the class is `'btn btn-default btn-sm'`? How do I access it in jQuery?

I tried `$('btn btn-default btn-sm')` but ut didn't work. Please help because I've been on this problem long enough.

Many thanks.

**My jQuery Code**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btn.btn-outline.btn-sm').click(function() {
                var pollQId = $('.btn.btn-outline.btn-sm').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/LikePoll",
                    data: JSON.stringify({'pollQId': pollQId}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $('.btn.btn-outline.btn-sm').addClass(msg.d)
                    },

                    error: function(response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        })
```

The above code works for all buttons in the repeater with the class in the jQuery selector. I need it to work for only the button clicked in the repeater. Thanks.

Comment: If you want it to be selected based on having all the classes you simply do `$('.btn.btn-default.btn-sm')` this will match any button that has all the listed classes. To go more broad, then just drop more of the specifics at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having multiple **class** hare so **two** possible case here:

1) If you want **union** of all class then use

```
$('.btn, .btn-default, .btn-sm')
```

2) If you want **intersection** of all **class** then use

```
$('.btn.btn-default.btn-sm')
```

Comment: Brilliant it worked. But just before I mark it as answer, the button is actually in the ItemTemplate of a repeater. And in my jQuery ajax code, I add a class to the clicked button when operation is successful. But instead it adds class to all the buttons in the repeater. How can I make it just the one I clicked? Thanks again.

Comment: if i understand correct then you should add the class on .click() function. if i am wrong then please share your code to understand the whole case.

Comment: It is actually in a click() function but it applies to every button in the repeater with the class I used in the jQuery selector. Please see the edited question for the code.

Comment: however i am unable to see your code but as i am getting, you should use like  

$('.btn.btn-default.btn-sm').click(function (){
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    });

and i think you might using '.btn.btn-default.btn-sm' instead of this

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I changed `$('.btn.btn-outline.btn-sm').addClass(msg.d)` to `$(this).addClass(msg.d)`. But it didn't work. Please note that `msg.d` is a string of css class that my code on server side returns.

Comment: it should be $(this).addClass("msg.d");  --- msg.d should be under " ".

Comment: You're a life saver. Thanks.